# Find characters up to first occurrence of '\' in string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string with emails/numbers that is separated by `\`. I am trying to get the first full email or number at the beginning of the string.

```
string = "test@test.com\test@gmail.com\12345678\"
result # => "test@test.com"

string = "1236784464\test@test.com\test@gmail.com\12345678\"
result # => "1236784464"
```

I have been trying to do index of the first `\` or match, but am not getting the regex right. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `split("\").first`

Comment: You should double the backslashes to define literal backslashes. And then [`"test@test.com\\test@gmail.com\\12345678\\".split("\\").first`](https://ideone.com/Isc1pw) will work.

Comment: If you are going to `split` and only need the first element, you should [pass a limit to it](https://ideone.com/sSs8iH)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this also with regular expression.

`string[/([^\\]+)/, 1]`

Comment: This would return an incorrect result, if the backslash is the first character in the string and you have another backslash further down. Also, I don't think you need the `,1` part, and the grouping. I would write it as `string[/[^\\]*/]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
"test@test.com\\test@gmail.com\\12345678\\"[/[^\\]+/]
# => "test@test.com"

"1236784464\\test@test.com\\test@gmail.com\\12345678\\"[/[^\\]+/]
# => "1236784464"
```